# How to I get a FriendlyURL in Razor?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

Anyone know how I can turn the URL from:
www.contoso.com/locations?Country=Vietnam
into
www.contoso.com/Vietnam

in Razor, C#, Webforms.  (I'm using Webmatrix)

ie - to create FriendlyURLS from search results.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `RouteConfig.cs`, add the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Vietnam",
    "{vietnam}",
    new { controller = "NameOfYourController", action = "NameOfYourAction" },
    new { vietnam = UrlParameter.Optional  }
);
```

You have to specify the name of the controller (without the word *controller*) and the action which will process the request.

Comment: Thanks @CodingYoshi but I'm not using MVC - rather Web Forms under Webmatrix.  (I've just updated by request for clarification)

Comment: @Mark I'm not an expert on web but as far as I know you can configure routing in WebForms as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx